# NestJS Missing Dependency

Tags: node.js, backend, nestjs

i'm facing an issue with NestJS :

"[Nest] 5068  - 08/11/2021, 3:12:02 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available in the AppModule context."

I tried to add AppService in the imports with no luck.

How to evade this error?

app.module.ts :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [User],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.controller.ts :

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Controller('api')
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {
    
  }

  @Post('register')
  async register(
    @Body('name') name: string,
    @Body('email') email: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
    @Body('phone') phone: string,
  ) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    return this.appService.create({
      name,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      phone,
    })
  }
}
```

app.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {
  }

  async create(data: any): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.save(data)
  }

}
```

user.entiry.ts :

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    phone: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `TypeormModule.forFeature([User])` to your `imports` in your `AppModule` to set up the `@InjectRepository(User)` that you make use of. With the TypeORM module, `forRoot/Async` is for database connection and general TypeORM configuration, `forFeature` is for dynamic provider setup